# <T extends Comparable<T>>

Tags: java, generics

Why does test1 cause an error while test2 does not? According to test2, `<T extends Comparable<T>>`. But **Manager** implements `Comparable<Employee>`, not `Comparable<Manager>`, so why doesn't test2 cause an error?

```java
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>{...}
 
public class Manager extends Employee{...}
 
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void test1(List<T> t){ }
 
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void test2(T t){ }
 
--------------------
 
List<Manager> listManager = new ArrayList<>();
 
test1(listManager);        //ERROR
 
test2(new Manager());
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EbDe.png)

Error message:

```
Required type:List<T>
Provided:List<Manager>
reason: Incompatible equality constraint: Employee and Manager
```

**Any suggestion would be appreciated.
Thank you.**

Comment: Please replace the image with text. We discourage images when text will do. Personally, I can't access that image from my work network and so can't help answer your question. A lot of other readers are in the same situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that `T` can be any reference type. You are assuming that the compiler chooses `T` to be `Manager`, but if it does so, your code will, as you said, fail to compile. The compiler's job is  to compile your code, so it will try to find a `T` such that your code does compile.

If `T` is `Employee`, the code would compile. `Employee` implements `Comparable<Employee>`. You can also pass a `Manager` to a parameter of type `Employee`, since `Manager` inherits from `Employee`, so all is good.

In `test1` however, no `T` will make your code compile. Suppose `T` is `Manager`, but`Manager` doesn't implement `Comparable<Manager>`. Suppose `T` is `Employee`, but [`List<Manager>` can't be passed to a parameter of type `List<Employee>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po).

Comment: Just to note, `test1` can be made to compile by changing the bound to `Comparable<? super T>`.